# Facebook Feed - All products show as... Out of Stock

Tags: facebook

I upload products to my Facebook Shop via a feed. All products are marked as "in stock" in the feed that gets uploaded. When I go to the catalog manager, all the newly uploaded products are there and correctly show as "in stock". One would think all is good; however, when I go to the actual public Shop page, all products are marked as "Out of stock".

I contacted Facebook and the reply I got was...

> I know how frustrating it may be to not have the products show as
>   desired. My support team who assisted with the investigation has
>   informed me that we do not currently support issues related to the
>   Facebook Shop.

I am not sure for certain if I am missing a step or if there is some additional code needed or anything else I must do... or if Facebook is just broken.

I have included all the columns that are marked as "required" and a few of the optional ones.

Here is the array from my code that shows which columns I include in the feed.

```
array(
    "id",
    "title",
    "description",
    "availability",
    "condition",
    "price",
    "link",
    "image_link",
    "mpn",
    "additional_image_link",
    "item_group_id",
    "pattern",
    "product_type",
    "sale_price",
    "sale_price_effective_date",
    "shipping_weight"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-feed-setup

Look at "mpn" field:

> Daily Deals inventory must also include brand if mpn is provided.

In your array brand is missing

Try to add the field to see if anything changes

Otherwise, please put the entire csv to see if anything is wrong